# How to convert Pandas Dataframe coming from RDD.mapPartitions() into Spark DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I've got a Python function that returns a Pandas DataFrame. I'm calling this function in Spark 2.2.0 using pyspark's [`RDD.mapPartitions()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions). But I can't convert the RDD returned by `mapPartitions()` into a Spark DataFrame. Pandas generates this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Simple code which illustrates the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def func(data):
    pdf = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=("A", "B", "C"))
    pdf += 10 # Add 10 to every value. The real function is a lot more complex!
    return [pdf]

pdf = pd.DataFrame([(1.87, 0.6, 7.1), (-0.3, 0.1, 8.2), (2.8, 0.3, 6.1), (-0.2, 0.5, 5.9)], columns=("A", "B", "C"))

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf.show()
rddIn = sdf.rdd

for i in rddIn.collect():
    print(i)

result = rddIn.mapPartitions(func)

for i in result.collect():
    print(i)

resDf = spark.createDataFrame(result) # --> ValueError!
resDf.show()
```

The output is:

```
+----+---+---+
|   A|  B|  C|
+----+---+---+
|1.87|0.6|7.1|
|-0.3|0.1|8.2|
| 2.8|0.3|6.1|
|-0.2|0.5|5.9|
+----+---+---+
Row(A=1.87, B=0.6, C=7.1)
Row(A=-0.3, B=0.1, C=8.2)
Row(A=2.8, B=0.3, C=6.1)
Row(A=-0.2, B=0.5, C=5.9)
       A     B     C
0  11.87  10.6  17.1
     A     B     C
0  9.7  10.1  18.2
      A     B     C
0  12.8  10.3  16.1
     A     B     C
0  9.8  10.5  15.9
```

but the second to last line produces the `ValueError` mentioned above. I really want `resDf.show()` to look exactly the same as `sdf.show()` except with 10 added to every value in the table. Ideally the `result` RDD should have the same structure as `rddIn`, the RDD going in to `mapPartitions()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert data to standard Python types and flatten:

```
resDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    result.flatMap(lambda df: (r.tolist() for r in df.to_records()))
)

resDF.show()
# +---+------------------+----+----+                                              
# | _1|                _2|  _3|  _4|
# +---+------------------+----+----+
# |  0|11.870000000000001|10.6|17.1|
# |  0|               9.7|10.1|18.2|
# |  0|              12.8|10.3|16.1|
# |  0|               9.8|10.5|15.9|
# +---+------------------+----+----+
```

If you use Spark 2.3 this should also work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, spark_partition_id
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf(sdf.schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)  
def func(pdf):
    pdf += 10 
    return pdf

sdf.groupBy(spark_partition_id().alias("_pid")).apply(func)
```

Comment: Thanks - I wouldn't have gotten this in a million years! And if you use `df.to_records(index=False)` you don't get the first column with the index values.